# Concatenate strings in dataframe rows (Python - pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following dataframe d1:

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1': ["A", "C"], 'col2': ["B", "D"]})
```

[image]

I want to built a dataframe d2 with a single row. That row would concatenate the values of d1's rows, separated by a space. That is:

```
d2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1': ["A B"], 'col2': ["C D"]})
```

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `agg` to operate `join`. However, it will return a `pd.Series`, so convert it to a dataframe with `pd.Series.to_frame`:

```
d2 = d1.agg(' '.join).to_frame().T
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pandas.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for iterating over rows then rename columns like `0 -> col1 & 1 -> col2`.

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1': ["A", "C"], 'col2': ["B", "D"]})
res = pd.DataFrame(d1.apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row), axis=1)).T.rename(columns = lambda x: f'col{x+1}')
print(res)
```

---

```
  col1 col2
0  A B  C D
```

Answer (score 2):

Join the rows together with [pd.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with axis=1, convert the result to list and pass it to a new dataframe. The columns you can take from d1.

```py
d2 = pd.DataFrame([d1.apply(" ".join, axis=1).tolist()], columns=d1.columns)
print(d2)
```

```
  col1 col2
0  A B  C D
```