# Convert missing values in a DataFrame to a given data type (Python - Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame d1 with strings and missing values, such as

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame([["A", "B", "C"],
                   ["D", np.nan, "F"],
                   ["G", "H", "I"],],
                  columns=[1, 2, 3])
```

[image]

whose columns I would like to aggregate in single-row DataFrame d2:

[image]

Folllowing suggestions in a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73505129/concatenate-strings-in-dataframe-rows-python-pandas/73505884#73505884), tried the following code:

```
d2 = d1.agg(''.join).to_frame().T
```

Still, as one of the values in d1 was missing (and, thus, a float), I got the following error:

> TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found

Would you know how to change missing values in DataFrames to another data type such as string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas dataframe fillna() only some columns in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134012/pandas-dataframe-fillna-only-some-columns-in-place)

Answer (score 1):

You can fill the missing value with an empty string:

```py
d1.fillna('')
```

So the overall code becomes

```py
d1.fillna('').agg(''.join).to_frame().T
```

```py
     1   2    3
0  ADG  BH  CFI
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a replace for nan values into ''

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame([["A", "B", "C"],
                   ["D", np.nan, "F"],
                   ["G", "H", "I"],],
                  columns=['1', '2', '3'])
d1.replace(np.nan,'',inplace=True)
d2 = d1.agg(''.join,axis=1).to_frame().T
```

Answer (score 1):

The null value is causing the error, so fill it with empty string. You could try this:

```
d2 = pd.DataFrame(d1.fillna('').agg(''.join)).T
print(d2)

     1   2    3
0  ADG  BH  CFI
```